# Arduino 5v pin outputting lower power than expected

Tags: voltage-level, arduino-nano-ble

I have hooked the pin v5 of an Arduino Nano 33 BLE to the A0 pin and measured the value by doing `Serial.println(analogRead(A0));`. I would expect to see 1023 however instead I see the value oscillating around 810.

Any ideas why I am not getting 1023?

P.S.: I am powering the Arduino board through the USB connector.

Comment: You should probably stop doing that until you have an answer.

Comment: use a voltmeter

Comment: it is not `lower power` ... it is `lower voltage` ... the two are not the same thing

Comment: I hope you didn't  solder the 5 V pin pads on the bottom side of the board. the 5 V pins is not connected to not make 5 V circuits just like you did. because the input pins on this board are for 3.3 V max. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/NANO33BLE#please-read

Comment: @Juraj I have soldered the 5v pin, because my sensors both require 5v. I have a Beetle Bluno BLE board that outputs 5v, I don't really understand the limitation. How am I supposed to power the sensors, with an extra external 5v power source?

Comment: and why do you wire 5 V to A0?

Comment: Because I don't have a voltmeter, so that was the only way for me to see what value was coming out from the 5v pin

Comment: With a divider it should be an okay way to measure.  If you connect A0 to your 3.3V pin, do you not see 1023 (or so) then?

Comment: Yes I see around 1023 if I connect A0 to my 3.3V pin

Comment: Well, that's the last thing I could think to ask that could disconfirm what I think is going on.  If I think of anything else, I'll ask.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I thought by now someone else would have answered it.  But, I'll try.  I'm not familiar with this chip and board, so what I can tell you is pretty limited.

In short, you have a 3.3V micro-controller and generally speaking you don't hook 5V signals to them.  There are some 3.3V parts that have "5V tolerant" inputs, but that only makes sense for digital inputs so far as I know.

Barring anything unpleasant happening, the behaviour I would expect to see with hooking 5V to the input of a 3.3V ADC is that it would clip at the high end value.  So yeah, for 10-bit resolution, which [appears to be the default](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/zero-due-mkr-family/analogreadresolution/) for the Nano 33 BLE and with VDD as the reference, which also [appears to be the default](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/), I would expect to see a value at or near 1023.  Up until the point that you fry something that is.

I don't know why you're seeing lower values, but since you seem to be operating it out of specifications, I'm not sure that really matters why.  If you want to measure 5V with your 3.3V max ADC, you should involve a voltage divider.

Comment: the 5 V pin is not connected from factory on this board

Comment: Again, I don't know what you're talking about.  If you have an answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/NANO33BLE#please-read

Comment: It's nice that they have an official warning about it.  The O.P. seems to remain unconvinced, for what reason I don't know.